# I can't assign variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I try to assign the value of "data.pic_name" to "imgSrc" by this following code

```js
var imgSrc = '';
$.ajax({
     url : "../NanglaeGov/getOneProPicture.do?owner="+data[i].tour_id,
     type : "POST",
     success : function(data) {
    imgSrc = data.pic_name;
    alert(imgSrc);
     },
      error : function(data, status, er) {
   alert('error');
   $("#loader").hide();
          }
     });
alert(imgSrc);
```

When it alert in the loop imgSrc has a value of data.pic_name but alert at the last line is completely blank.

Comment: when the alert is executed, the ajax call may not have returned yet. you should move the alert *inside* the `success` part of the call

Comment: Thanks @Quentin for leading me to the right question, I didn't really see that.

Comment: Thanks Federico klez Culloca I can see my problem now. ^_^